LCR meter U1733C - R range mesurement
I have the LCR meter "U1733C" and I am little confused about the "R" scale. As I understand (the manual doesn't say it clear - maybe it is self-evident and I am missing something) in "Ζ" scale it measures the Complex Impedance [ Z(Complex Impedance) = R(resistance) + jX(Reactive Component) ] at fixed frequencies where are 100Hz, 120Hz, 1KHz, 10KHz, 100KHz, but in "R" scale why it measures the resistance in the same frequencies (manual page 49)? Isn't suppose the "R" scale measures the resistance where is the real part of the Complex Impedance where it is the same independently of the changing of the frequency? Also, this LCR meter has DCR (Direct Current Resistance; measures the resistance by applying 1VDC Voltage / manual page 55).

The LCR meter cannot measure the equivalent series resistance ESR of a capacitor by applying a dc current. The ESR may be frequency dependent for real elements. It is an ac value.

I agree, but this LCR meter have different mode for mesuring specifically the ESR.
